# Item search macro

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have an Excel macro that searches the item number from the website and scrap some specific information from the web page like availability, price, page URL. But after scraping some pages, it gives me this error:

> Runtime error 91, Object variable or With block variable not set

I don't know why this is happening again and again.  This macro also works very slowly. Is it possible to work with all the Internet Explorers (IE9, IE10, IE11 etc.)?  Can anyone fix this one?

I have Office 2007 and IE9.

```
Sub xtremeExcel()
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Visible = True
oBrowser.navigate "http://cpc.farnell.com/"
Do
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

For i = 3 To Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document
    xc = 0
    Do While (HTMLDoc.getElementById("searchTerms") Is Nothing)
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
        xc = xc + 1
        If xc > 15 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("searchTerms").Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("go").Click

    xc = 0
    flag = 0
    Do While (HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("prodDetailAvailability")(0) Is Nothing)
        Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
        xc = xc + 1
        If xc > 15 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    If HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("prodDetailAvailability")(0) Is Nothing Then
         xc = 0
        Do While (HTMLDoc.getElementById("totalNoResultsSlotAtTop") Is Nothing)
            Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
            xc = xc + 1
            If xc > 10 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        flag = 2
    End If


    If flag <> 2 Then
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = Replace(HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("prodDetailAvailability")(0).innerText, "Availability: ", "")
        unitprice = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("unitprice")(0).innerText
        If InStr(1, unitprice, "(") > 0 Then
            Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value = Replace(Left(unitprice, InStr(1, unitprice, "(") - 1), "Unit Price: ", "")
            Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value = Mid(unitprice, InStr(1, unitprice, "(") + 1, InStr(1, unitprice, ")") - 1 - (InStr(1, unitprice, "(")))
        Else
            Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value = unitprice
        End If

        Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value = oBrowser.LocationURL
    Else
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = "Not Found"
    End If
 oBrowser.GoBack
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: HTMLDoc.getElementById("searchTerms").Value = Cells(i, 1).Value

Answer (score 0):

## **tl;dr;**

You can loop in the fashion shown below; waiting for an item to be set.

The function  `WaitUntilReady`  loops until  `.document.getElementById("sProdList")` can be set. That is the table which holds the information to return. You may wish to add some error handling and a timeout so loop doesn't risk an infinite cycle.

I have listed 2 search terms in the `searchTerms` array. You can extend this. It concantenates the search term into the URL, so goes direct rather than always hitting landing and a re-direct.

**Note:**

I would look into whether there is an API available if planning on doing alot of searches or looping search result pages. The below only does the first page of each but is already giving you a ton of code to work with. Your IP will be blocked if attempting XHR so method below is a compromise. I would love to ditch IE from any solution.

---

## **Example page results:**

### [image: sample results]

## **Example code output:**

[image: Sample code output]

---

## **VBA:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer, a As HTMLTable, wsTarget As Worksheet, currSearch As Long, searchTerms
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    wsTarget.UsedRange.ClearContents
    searchTerms = Array("CCTV", "FANS")
    
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        ApplyHeaders wsTarget
        For currSearch = LBound(searchTerms) To UBound(searchTerms)
            .navigate "http://cpc.farnell.com/search?st=" & searchTerms(currSearch) & "&aka_re=1"

            Set a = WaitUntilReady(IE)

            Dim allRows As Object,classNames()
            Set allRows = a.getElementsByClassName("altRow")
            classNames = Array("productImage mftrPart", "sku", "description", "availability", "priceFor", "priceBreak")
    
            Dim i As Long, y As Long, r As Long, tempString As String, j As Long, k As Long
            r = GetLastRow(wsTarget, 1) + 1
           
            For i = 0 To allRows.Length - 1
                For j = LBound(classNames) To UBound(classNames)
                    For k = 0 To allRows(i).getElementsByClassName(classNames(j)).Length - 1
                        tempString = tempString & vbNewLine & TidyString(allRows(i).getElementsByClassName(classNames(j))(k).innerText)
                    Next k
                    With wsTarget
                        .Cells(r, j + 1).Value = tempString
                    End With
                    tempString = vbNullString
                Next j
                r = r + 1
            Next i
            r = r + 1
        Next currSearch
        .Quit
    End With
    TidySheet wsTarget
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByRef ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Public Function TidyString(ByVal inputString As String) As String
    TidyString = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(inputString)
    TidyString = Trim$(Replace$(Replace$(TidyString, Chr$(10), vbNullString), vbCrLf, vbNullString))
End Function
   
Public Sub ApplyHeaders(ByVal wsTarget As Worksheet)
    Dim headers(), i As Long
    headers = Array("Manufacturer Part No", "Order Code", "Manufacturer / Description", "Avail", "Price For", "Price Ex. VAT (Inc. VAT)")
    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        wsTarget.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = headers(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function WaitUntilReady(ByVal IE As InternetExplorer) As HTMLTable
    With IE
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set WaitUntilReady = .document.getElementById("sProdList")
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While WaitUntilReady Is Nothing
    End With
End Function

Public Sub TidySheet(ByVal wsTarget As Worksheet)
    With wsTarget
        .Rows("2:" & .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row).RowHeight = 25
        .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```